# String Manipulation: Find the discount of a price/number while in a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I had a technical interview and this question was particularly hard for me to answer. Not sure how to go about this issue, would really appreciate if someone helped me figure out this question.

You have a string that states the price of an item. You want to return a string with the all the numbers 15% off the original number.

```
example.)

if an item was 15% off

input string:

str1 = "This person bought an iphone for $500 and a macbook for $1400"

output string:

str2 = "This person bought an iphone for $425 and a macbook for $1190"
```

I know I should split the string, and probably locate all the numbers that proceeds a "$" symbol but I am not sure how to go from there.

Comment: using a regular expression + a callback to find and replace numbers would be a good solution that demonstrates your programming maturity well to an interviewer.

Comment: javascript is related to java like carpet is related to car. so, which is it?

Comment: Read the tag `JavaScript (not to be confused with Java)` before you tag.

Comment: Its an interview question so I guess its your own personal preference. I can read both Javascript and java I just want to understand how to get to the answers/different ways to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @goat's idea

```
var x = "This person bought an iphone for $500 and a macbook for $1400";

function getDiscount(str) {
  var origPrices = str.match(/(\d{1,})/gi);
  var discountPrices = origPrices.map(function(value) {
     return value - value * 0.15;
  });
  origPrices.forEach(function(currentvalue, index){
    str = str.replace(currentvalue, discountPrices[index]);
  });
  return str;
}
getDiscount(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `String.replace` with a `RegExp` and a callback receiving the full match and the matching group as parameters:

```js
let str = "This person bought an iphone for $500 and a macbook for $1400"

let result = str.replace(/\$(\d+)/g, (match, price) => '$' + 0.85 * price);

console.log(result);
```

I assumed you only want to match prices preceded by a dollar symbol. Depending on your needs, you could refine the `RegExp` to match prices with decimal points etc.

Comment: Never knew about the string replace callback. great answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "This person bought an iphone for $500 and a macbook for $1400";
        int index = input.indexOf('$');
        int inNumber = 0;
        String number = "";

        while (inNumber != -1) {
            inNumber++;
            char temp = input.charAt(index + inNumber);
            int value = Character.getNumericValue(temp);
            if (value >= 0 && value < 10) {
                number = number + value;
            } else
                break;
            if(temp==' ')
                break;
        }
```

in variable number, you have got your first numeric, and again run the method to get the second, by  using `String.subString(index)`
and running the same process again, use `Integer.parseInt()` to get the int calcuate discounts and replace it with original index respectively , you know starting indexes of both strings
this is  a quick logic if you do not know the regex at the interview